# SeqGAN - Policy gradient objective function interpretation

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, generative-adversarial-networks, reinforce, seq2seq

Could someone clear my doubt on the loss function used in [SeqGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05473.pdf) . The paper uses policy gradient method to train the generator which is a recurrent neural network here.

1. Have I interpreted the terms correctly?
2. What are we summing over? The entire vocabulary of words?

Loss function - my interpretation:
[image]

Comment: Try to ask a more specific question and simplify the post. In that way, I think you will attract more people and potentially someone that attempts to answer your question. If you have multiple questions, I suggest that you create 1 post for each of the questions (even if they are related) for the simple reason that simplicity/clarity often attracts more people.

Comment: @nbro Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the excess questions because my core doubt is what the term under the summation indicates